# rotate 3d object with mous down every where in screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is an object which is moving forward by setting its velocity to forward with some speed. This is working fine. I want to map mouse down rotation on that moving object by touching anywhere on the screen while moving forward.

Comment: This was asked and answered so often before ... please do some research and come back with a code example of what you tried so far and with a clear specific coding related problem

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @derHugo will u share that post link?